# javascript stacking bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
 $jq('.pop-tip').click( function(event) {
        width = '';
        height = '';
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            width = 'width='+(this.width + 240);
            height = 'height='+(this.height + 360);              
        }
        img.src = 'http://www.domain.com/uploads/2011/10/dealoftheweek.jpg';        
        destination = $jq(this).attr('title');
        postPop = $jq(this).attr('href');
        alert ( width );
        window.open(postPop, 'tip_pop',''+ width +', '+ height +', scrollbars=0' ).focus();
        window.open(destination, '_parent','' );
        event.preventDefault();
)};
```

For some reason it only works with the alert() just above the window.open call why is this and how can i fix it?

Comment: Everytime you post a question about `alert()` delaying execution and making things work, a fairy dies asynchronously

Comment: If your code doesn't do what it's supposed to, then how are we supposed to determine what it's supposed to do from it?

Comment: Try popping up your js console (shift-ctrl-J in FF/Chrome) to see if there's any errors between the two versions.

Comment: As Tomalak hilariously hints at, your onLoad function is the last thing to execute, thus normally width and height haven't been set yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you are setting height and width in onload event which will occur only after image is totally loaded. 
Putting an alert will let the image load completely, by the time you click alert's ok, the image's onload will get called and the values would be set. But if u remove that, the height and width values are not set and so it would not work.

you can fix this by calling rest of the code inside the onload event.

Answer (score 1):

Image load is asynchronous; the code continues executing while your image loads. Then you hit the `window.open` line, which needs `width` and `height`, which are not yet defined. A few milliseconds later, your image loads, and so do your `width` and `height`.

With the `alert`, you delay the `window.open` call long enough for the image to finish loading, and the dimension variables will be ready to be used when you click the "OK" button.

The solution is to stuff the `window.open`, and everything that depends on the data from the image, inside the `img.onload` handler function.

EDIT: damn, I type slowly :P And Tomalak... ROFL